# How to determine the correct number of connections

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to determine the number of connections there are on my db, I found the following queries and results from the net and both have very different outputs. Can anyone tell me which figure correctly shows the number of connections on the db and how to get more details on these connections?

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(host, ':', 1) AS host_short,
    ->        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT USER)   AS users,
    ->        COUNT(*)
    -> FROM   information_schema.processlist
    -> GROUP  BY host_short
    -> ORDER  BY COUNT(*),
    ->           host_short;
+------------+-------------+----------+
| host_short | users       | COUNT(*) |
+------------+-------------+----------+
| localhost  | root,mailer |        7 |
+------------+-------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show status like 'Conn%';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Connections   | 9885  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the desire result using the query like as bellow-

```
SELECT 
    db_name(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as ConnNo,
    loginame as Login
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
;
```

Comment: i tried that command and got ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION db_name does not exist
i tried switching db_name with databases but got the following error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'databases(dbid) as DBName,      COUNT(dbid) as ConnNo,     loginame as Login FRO' at line 1